# Controlled points on faces

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, instances

I am new to Blender. I want to create a couple of 3D structures resembling the attached 2D porous structure for scientific publication [image: 2D porous structure1]

I was able to create the first part with some help from this community. However, the nanoparticles in the interior wall appear to float.

1. I need them to be located on the interior wall, similar to the 2D image (left side figure). Also, I need to get rid of the particles floating on top (please see the attached 3D image).

   [image: 3D structure2]
2. Secondly, I need to coat the interior walls with another semi-transparent layer similar to the attached 2D image (right side figure). Is there any simple way to create this layer?

I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Thanks in advance!!

[image: Geometry node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** in order to get rid of the particles on the "walls" you can use a `Geometry Proximity` on the cube it self and a `Delete Geometry`.

[image]

For the shader i certainly didn't understood what you want... Is a volume shader will do the trick?

[image]

The result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. This will do :)

Comment: Regarding the shader, I want to create another additional layer that would coat the internal wall or the curved surfaces as well as the nanoparticles.